# Decision tree too small

Tags: r, data-mining, decision-trees

I have a data set of 2300 entries, with 5 variables one of them the dependent variable which is binary.

I fitted a decision try using the `rpart` function in R over the 4 independent variables, and I had this tiny tree, which means the split was done using only one predictive variable.

Is it normal? How can I add the rest of the nodes?
[image: resulting tree graphic]

Comment: We can't know unless you give more information. Maybe the data was perfectly separated using that variable. Maybe the decision tree used a fraction of the features as a regularization technique. Maybe you set a maximum depth of 2, or some other parameter that prevents additional splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the max depth parameter? This parameter limits the depth of each tree. If you have set it up to max_depth=1 you wont be able to grow your tree further.

From the documentation:

> max_depthint, default=None
>   The maximum depth of the tree. If None, then nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than min_samples_split samples.

Also, it could be that you have your target on the train and your tree does not need to develop further.

Or that you are training with a small number of rows or columns

Comment: That's the documentation for sklearn, not rpart; but the hyperparameter plays the same role, in rpart it is called `maxdepth`.  To the last two points, you can see in the graphic how many samples of each class live in each leaf; with rpart's default `minsplit=20`, it should be able to split further.  Maybe it's the `cp` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, I don't advise use lib **rpart**, if it's not necessary. It's quite hard to set up and he has often unexplainable behavior. 
If is required **R**, then choose **rpart** with module **prp** or **ctree**.
Sample code with output:

```
#Churn its **factor** binary variable so I use method="class"
#minbucket - the minimum number of observations in any terminal leaf


fit<-rpart(Churn~., data=data_train, method = "class",minbucket=50)
prp(fit) # fancy way of draw decison tree and setup
```

Other parameters to set up the decision tree you will find [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-15/topics/rpart.control).

**Sample output**:

[image]

Comment: Ctree is based on some conditional inference thing and i just wanted the one with the entropy criteria, the package tree seems to do the trick, i have another issue, one of the numeeocal variables appeared twice, it was used for the first cut and for the second cut on the left, is that normal ?

Comment: Yes, it is normal,  any feature can be used multiple times in a tree.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem normal. 
It seems to be a case of **leakage**. 
It might be possible that "*Taux.Brut.de.Reusite.Serie.S*" is highly correlated to the Dependent variable.

**An example** - 
If I keep *sugar_level* as an independent variable and *IsDiebetic* as a dependent then one simple condition on *sugar_level* will split the whole data correctly.

Comment: It is indeed highly correlated with the dependent variable, i have changed the package from rpart to tree and it gave me a slightly bigger tree with good performance measures with minimal entropy, thank you guys for your feed back i appreciate it

Comment: Please help with answer acceptance. It helps the community